# how can i set kivy widgets position platform independently?

Tags: kivy

I'm writing an application with `kivy` that scans a network and based on results it generates bunch of widget like labels and buttons or maybe a layout like `Gridview`.

I'm trying to position them by `pos` or `center_x` and `center_y` attributes. I can position them perfectly on my laptop but when I try my tablet or other devices with different screen sizes everything goes wrong and all widgets change their position.

My question is:
Is there a elegant way to position widgets and layouts that pertain their position on any screen size?

P.S:

it's not working even when i maximize the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many different options here like::

1. Query the [Window](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html) size and position your widget relative to the window using percentages instead of absulute values.
2. Use specific [layout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) that fits the positioning style you need for you widgets.

**Recomended**

1. Use [pos_hint](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html) in combination with your layouts
2. specify the widget pos using [kivy.metrics](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint).dp which gives you device independent pixels or use metrics.sp/cm/mm/in/...

Comment: any recommendation for a good tutorial on kivy? the guide section in kivy website is not very user friendly for me.

Comment: try out the tutorials by Alexander Taylor. They should be mentioned on the landing page of http://kivy.org